# Tabs \n in list for python

Tags: python

I have simple script in python, want return per line the values

Tabs = # and \n

**SCRIPT**

```
output = ['192.168.0.1 #SRVNET\n192.168.0.254 #SRVDATA']

output =  output[0].split('#')
output.split('\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you split the first time, `output` is a list which doesn't support `.split`.

If splitting on two different items, you can use a regular expression with `re.split`:

```
>>> import re
>>> output = ['192.168.0.1 #SRVNET\n192.168.0.254 #SRVDADOS']
>>> re.split(r'\n|\s*#\s*',output[0]) # newline or comment (removing leading/trailing ws)
['192.168.0.1', 'SRVNET', '192.168.0.254', 'SRVDADOS']
```

You may want to group the IP with a comment as well, for example:

```
>>> [re.split(r'\s*#\s*',line) for line in output[0].splitlines()]
[['192.168.0.1', 'SRVNET'], ['192.168.0.254', 'SRVDADOS']]
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of the line :

> output =  output[0].split('#')

is actually a list. ".split" always returns a list. In your case the output looks like this:

```
['192.168.0.1 ', 'SRVNET\n192.168.0.254 ', 'SRVDATA']
```

And as the error rightly points out, a list cannot be "split" using the ".split" which it does not support.

So now if you wanna further split the list when "#" is encountered, then this can be solved by iterating through the list and calling the split function like this:

```
output=['192.168.0.1 ', 'SRVNET\n192.168.0.254 ', 'SRVDATA']
for i in output:
    if "\n" in i:
        print("yes")
        output_1=i.split("\n")
```

This will give the "output_1" as:

```
['SRVNET', '192.168.0.254 ']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `re`, then you need to apply `split("\n")` to each element of `output[0].split("#")`, then concatenate the results together again. One way to do that is

```
result = [y for x in output[0].split("#") for y in x.split("\n")]
```